# Strange content of excel file loaded with POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I obtained an excel (.xls) file that I cannot seem to load properly using POI libraries (versions tested 3.9, 3.10.1). The content of the file after loading goes along the lines of:

`,  DIM_1,  DIM_2,  DIM_3,  DIM_4,... ACTUAL,  0.0014,  16.0329,  240.4296,...  DIM_22MAX,  DIM_22MIN,  ,  ,...`

whereas the real content is:

```
Critical Parameters & Quality Data  

Manufacturing Supplier: 
Manufacturer Supplier name: ???  
Manufacturer Supplier code: 

Sampling    Sample Size:    1
...
```

**EDIT**
I have been updated that the file was generated using VBA.

The java code used:

```
    Workbook workbook;
    workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(fileInputStream);
    workbook.setMissingCellPolicy(Row.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);
    Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
    FormulaEvaluator evaluator = workbook.getCreationHelper()
            .createFormulaEvaluator();

    inputMatrix = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int j = 0; j <= sheet.getLastRowNum(); j++) {
        ArrayList<Object> tRow = new ArrayList<>();
        Row row = sheet.getRow(j);
        if (row != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < row.getLastCellNum(); i++) {
                Cell cell = row.getCell(i);
                if (cell == null)
                    tRow.add("");
                else
                    try {
                        switch (evaluator.evaluateInCell(cell)
                                .getCellType()) {
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                            String strVal = /*cell.getStringCellValue();*/ cell.getRichStringCellValue().toString(); 
                            tRow.add(strVal);
                            break;
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                            if (DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)) {
                                tRow.add(cell.getDateCellValue());
                            } else {
                                tRow.add(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                            }
                            break;
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                            tRow.add(cell.getBooleanCellValue());
                            break;
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA:
                            tRow.add(cell.getCellFormula());
                            break;
                        default:
                            tRow.add("");
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        tRow.add("ERR");
                        logger.error("error evaluating excel file, assigning ERR value to the cell.", e);
                    }
            }
        }
        inputMatrix.add(tRow);
    }
```

Any thoughts...?

Comment: Strange about the content is that it looks nothing like the thing  written above. I'll update the question to clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out, the problem was the first sheet that was hidden.